# Drop privileges for the current connection in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Is it possible to actively remove some permissions only for the current connection to the database?

There is a database user with all permissions to its dababase, which sometimes is necessary (schema changes are performed manually right now).

Most of the time the user is used to just perform some data retrieval.
Can I just "drop" all destructive privileges for the current connection so that nothing can happen to the data?

Or is it necessary for this to create a second user without the privileges?

I'm also thankful for any hints on how to search for this, because *drop* is a term leading to many things quite different from what I want to achieve in database context.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just "drop" all destructive privileges for the current connection so that nothing can happen to the data?

Sure you could [`REVOKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) any granted privileges of which are not needed by that User. But of course you need to specify which ones, there's no single command for just the "*destructive privileges*".

Note that a User could be gaining permissions from multiple roles in the database, and via multiple sources such as directly applied to that User and / or from any AD Groups that User is a part of (if it's tied to a Windows Login) which has a role applied to it. If you wanted to override that and prevent future granting of permissions undoing your removal, you may want to use [`DENY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) explicitly instead.

The only exception to all of this, is if the Login for that User is in the [`SysAdmin` server level role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-server-level-roles). They would need to be explicitly removed from that role, as `SysAdmin`s cannot be denied any permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the terms _REVOKE_ and _DENY_ for further searches.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping for a mechanism like dropping privileges after starting a process. The user keeps its privileges, but the current connection has eg no _DELETE_ privilege for the database.

Comment: Also take a look at Application Roles - this allows you to swap to use end user like permissions that you define yourself

Comment: @Dehalion "*I was hoping for a mechanism like dropping privileges after starting a process. The user keeps its privileges, but the current connection has eg no DELETE privilege for the database.* - Not sure I understand the distinction?...you can `REVOKE` or `DENY` a User's permissions, even during an active connection that has a running process.

Comment: @J.D. If I understand `REVOKE` correctly this is a permanent action removing privileges of the user itself, not just the current connection. I am looking for something which is bound to the current connection, so connecting again later results in the full privileges again.

Comment: @Dehalion Yes, you'd have to `REVOKE` and re-`GRANT` the permissions accordingly. You can only apply these to the User / Login, not a specific connection. Your use case isn't very clear to me though...what do you hope to accomplish by revoking the permissions for a given connection, especially after they've already started executing the code / processes they need?...once they are done with those processes, the connection should be closed (as it's unwise to keep a connection open for longer than a single unit of work - unless manually working ad-hocly). It sounds like you need more Users.

Comment: @J.D. We'll have to go with multiple users then. FYI the use case is that this is a system where we have to do manual schema changes as well as some manual individual reports/exports. If we need to just query data (for export/reporting) we don't want to accidentally modify data or schema.

Comment: @Dehalion It's generally best practice to use multiple Logins / Users, and furthermore really should be using the current executing domain user's account, so that permissions can be controlled more granularly / appropriately, to be honest. (Also, again, I hope your application isn't keeping connections open for multipe "*units of work*" at a time. It's important to not use long running connections.)